# Leaflet - Add Layer on LayerAdd event

Tags: javascript, leaflet

so i want to add a Layer if a other Layer is added .... 
i did make a small Example

```
var mymap = L.map('mymap').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);

var baseLayer = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    maxZoom: 18,
}).addTo(mymap);

var layer1 = L.marker([51.505,-0.10]);
var layer2 = L.marker([51.505,-0.09]);
var layer3 = L.marker([51.505,-0.8]);



var basemaps = {
    "OSM": baseLayer
};

var overlays = {
    "Layer1": layer1,
  "Layer2": layer2,
  "Layer3": layer3
}

L.control.layers(basemaps,overlays,{collapsed:false}).addTo(mymap);

layer1.on("add",function(){
    layer2.addTo(mymap);
});
```

and on

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xtg0nt6x/2/) (Updated Version)

Like you (may) can see the second Marker is shortly added but instantly removed after the add-Event is finished ... 
Iam not sure how i can prefent it from doing that or  more specific how i realy can add the second marker (since in the Layer Control the checkbox isnt even activated in that short moment) ....

Comment: jsfiddle does not work

Answer (score 2):

you can either use `map.on('layeradd')` and or try the `layeradd`
event on your `layer1` object.

leaflet's documentation link: http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.3.html#layerevent

EDIT... add the following code to js-fiddle code.

```
layer1.on('add',(e)=>{
  layer2.addTo(mymap);
});

layer1.addTo(mymap);
```

if that doesn't remove the addTo line from above and paste the following

```
setTimeout(()=>{
  layer1.addTo(mymap);
},500);
```

EDIT 2 :

```
var controlObj = L.control.layers(basemaps,overlays,{collapsed:false}).addTo(mymap);

layer1.on("add",function(){
 console.log(controlObj._form[2].click())
});
```

this code works... but its not how it should be dont... will have to figureout a better way to do this, but this will work temporarily.

Comment: so the `layeradd` event does not work on a layer-object

and the `map.on('layeradd')` still produces the same problem (layer shortly gets added but removed at the end of the event) 

See new (and this time opfully working) [JSFiddle][1]

See how 2 markers are shown while die Alert is open ... 

  [1]: https://jsfiddle.net/xtg0nt6x/2/

Comment: check out the edit i made to the answer. it is working.

Comment: ya that works ... but only if i add the layer1 with code ... i want to have the 2. layer added to if i use the LayerControl  ...

Comment: I have 3 Layers in My JSFiddle ... if the user adds Layer1 with the help of the LayerControl i also want to add Layer2. The Problem is with Code that Works so if i do `layer1.addTo(mymap)` that works but if the users uses the LayerControl it just disapears after the event has finished ....

Comment: added new code, it works but will have to find better way to do this. i think this is some sort of references error, because both `layer2` and your object of the `overlay` are referring to same `marker`.

Comment: thats also the only solution i could come up with but i dont like this since its not realy dynamic if the layer order changes i have to change that also ... i thought iam missing something obvious but seems like a "bug" in leaflet

Comment: i agree, its a rather bad way to do it.